# Why is my zip file not the same size as the zip file I'm trying to copy?

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm writing a python script to append files from an old jar file to the a new jar file, but the file size of the new file isn't exactly the same as the original file. The `original.jar` is 6,786 KB and the `patched.jar` is 6,773 KB. Before running script I deleted the `patched.jar` file.

```
import zipfile

zin = zipfile.ZipFile("original.jar")
zout = zipfile.ZipFile("patched.jar", 'a')

for entry in zin.infolist():
    buffer = zin.read(entry.filename)
    zout.writestr(entry, buffer)
```

I need the size to be exactly the same because they are jar files and don't need compression but I didn't find any solution. Is there anything I can do to get the new file to have the same size as the old file?

**Edit: It wasn't because of compression! One of the comments mentioned it was metadata and in 7zip I noticed that the original archive has files with `Characteristics` set to `Descriptor UTF8` while original has none.**

Comment: If you want exactly the same file,  but just renamed, why not just copy the file with the new name?

Comment: @Adrian Klaver i'm using krakout2 and when you assemble a jar file there's not all files so I add the other files from original jar file

Comment: What happens if you call [zout.close()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.close) after the for loop?

Comment: @President James K. Polk I edited the code to use `zout.close()` but there was not much difference.

Comment: If you do a binary comparison between them, can you see what the 13 bytes difference is?

Comment: A possible culprit is the "comment" field of the (global) EOCD, since the code here is not copying from the original to the patched. Some tools might use it to indicate what generated the archive?

Comment: Have you tried to use `zin.read_bytes()` instead of `zin.read()`?

Comment: > 

Note

The ZIP file standard historically did not specify a metadata encoding, but strongly recommended CP437 (the original IBM PC encoding) for interoperability. Recent versions allow use of UTF-8 (only). In this module, UTF-8 will automatically be used to write the member names if they contain any non-ASCII characters. It is not possible to write member names in any encoding other than ASCII or UTF-8.

Comment: @Claudio zin.read returns bytes or utf8 string, depends on what the file is.

Comment: Have you tried other methods? The Java tools might do something slightly different than standard zip. Also try unzipping and zipping a copy in the command line. See if the java and zip utilities report different information.

Comment: *"I need the size to be exactly the same"* - Why? (Your stated reason doesn't really make sense.)

Comment: Best you write an answer to your question yourself instead of giving an answer within the question. Then you can accept your own answer in one or two days to complete the question/answer cycle,

Comment: @KellyBundy why does it matter so much to you? I didn't want to explain because it was complicated but here you go. I am deassembling a minecraft launcher with krakout2, but the minecraft launcher (which is a jar file) checks integrity of the launcher. I wanted to deassemble and assemble the jar file but krakout2 didn't include assets so I'm using zipfile to add them. I just need to copy launcher files without failing the launcher integrity check

Comment: @JohnBayko unzipping and zipping it wouldn't work because it's obfuscated and it has files like jZ.class, jz.class. I'm using a standard zip because I didn't find any alternatives

Comment: Because often such questions have the XY problem.

Comment: @stavratum I was suggesting different methods because the tools might have diagnostics that could answer your question. As for the case sensitive file names, you can pipe the output of unzip to the input of zip, or in Windows you could try mounting a zip file as a drive.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you don't set the compression type!

Try this code...

Method.1:

```
import zipfile

zin = zipfile.ZipFile("original.jar")
zout = zipfile.ZipFile("patched.jar", 'w', zipfile.ZIP_STORED, compresslevel=0)

for entry in zin.infolist():
    buffer = zin.read(entry.filename)
    zout.writestr(entry, buffer)
```

Method.2:

```
import zipfile

zin = zipfile.ZipFile("original.jar")
zout = zipfile.ZipFile("patched.jar", 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, compresslevel=0)

for entry in zin.infolist():
    buffer = zin.read(entry.filename)
    zout.writestr(entry, buffer)
```

Comment: Didn't work. I think it doesn't use any compression level anyway

Comment: I am still researching